# Same SlidingDrawer in all activities?

Tags: android, slidingdrawer

I have a `slidingDrawer` in my application that contains links which should be accessed by all activities. Is it possible to create a single `slidingDrawer` and extend it to all activities? Any example would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best bet would be to create a parent class with all of the sliding drawer logic. The parent class would extend activity and make sure to setup / populate your sliding drawer, the data could possibly be a singleton also to avoid load duplication. Then all of your activities would extend your SlidingDrawer activity and do their thing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your solution but only xml layout of slidingDrawer appears. Here is the similar solution that I used: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922641/sliding-drawer-appear-in-all-activities