# Android: Combining layouts using FrameLayout - Layout Not Visible

Tags: android, android-activity, slidingdrawer, android-framelayout

I have multiple activities in my app and i want a slidingdrawer to appear in all the activities. I am following the approach given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922641/sliding-drawer-appear-in-all-activities/4922740#4922740).

The app starts with a black screen with the slidingdrawer handle.

Issue is that the sliding drawer is visible but the activity layout put in FarmeLayout is **not** visible.

The activity is there for sure. Toasts came up when the first activity loaded. So I modified my first activity to have only a button on it to go to next activity.

Next I used the direction keys on the AVD, and pressed ok which brought up the the next activity's Toast. Second activity is as well hidden.

So what am I missing???

My Sliding Drawer layout xml (LinearLayout) with farme layout at the end:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <SlidingDrawer
        android:id="@+id/slidingDrawer"
        android:handle="@+id/drawerHandle"
        android:content="@+id/contentLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:persistentDrawingCache="all">

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/drawerHandle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxHeight="5dp"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:background="#BB00FF"
            android:rotation="270"
            android:textOn=""
            android:textOff=""/>

        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/contentLayout"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo">

            <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:text="@string/list_view_" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </SlidingDrawer>

    <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/act_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="#808080"
    android:visibility="visible">
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

DrawerActivity java code:

```
public abstract class DrawerActivity extends Activity 
{
protected LinearLayout fullLayout;
protected FrameLayout actContent;

  @Override
  public void setContentView(final int layoutResID) 
  {
    fullLayout= (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.act_layout, null); // Your base layout here
    actContent= (FrameLayout) fullLayout.findViewById(R.id.act_content);
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID, actContent, true); // Setting the content of layout your provided to the act_content frame
    super.setContentView(fullLayout);
  }
}
```

In all my activitie files I have put `setContentView(R.layout.XXXXXXXX);` in the **onCreate** method.

So how do I make the activities visible?? What am I doing wrong??

I tried putting in the following but to no effect

```
actContent.setVisibility(layoutResID); 
or 
actContent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: found the problem.
Had to put the following line android:layout_weight="1" into slidingdrawer in the xml. Also, one of my activity was using a listview. The list view would hide the slidingdrawer. For that I used  actContent.bringChildToFront((View) findViewById(R.id.slidingDrawer));

Comment: And also brought sliding drawer under farmelayout..