# How to Display Navigation Drawer in all activities?

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer, android-actionbar-compat

I have a `Navigation Drawer` which should appear in all my activities.

I saw many questions similar to this & found a solution like Extending the MainActivity with the Other Activities .

So i extended My Main Activity to my Second Activity.But the Drawer is not being showed in the Second Activity

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawer;
    private CustomActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private String[] menuItems;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    supportRequestWindowFeature(WindowCompat.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    // getSupportActionBar().hide();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_drawer);

    // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer
    // opens
    mDrawer.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);

    _initMenu();
    mDrawerToggle = new CustomActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawer);
    mDrawer.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

}

private void _initMenu()
{
    NsMenuAdapter mAdapter = new NsMenuAdapter(this);

    // Add Header
    mAdapter.addHeader(R.string.ns_menu_main_header);

    // Add first block

    menuItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ns_menu_items);
    String[] menuItemsIcon = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ns_menu_items_icon);

    int res = 0;
    for (String item : menuItems)
    {

        int id_title = getResources().getIdentifier(item, "string", this.getPackageName());
        int id_icon = getResources().getIdentifier(menuItemsIcon[res], "drawable", this.getPackageName());

        NsMenuItemModel mItem = new NsMenuItemModel(id_title, id_icon);
        // if (res==1) mItem.counter=12; //it is just an example...
        // if (res==3) mItem.counter=3; //it is just an example...
        mAdapter.addItem(mItem);
        res++;
    }

    mAdapter.addHeader(R.string.ns_menu_main_header2);

    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    if (mDrawerList != null)
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.control_menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

/* Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content
    // view
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawer.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_keyboard).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    /*
     * The action bar home/up should open or close the drawer.
     * ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
     */
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
    {
        return true;
    }

    // Handle your other action bar items...
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private class CustomActionBarDrawerToggle extends ActionBarDrawerToggle
{

    public CustomActionBarDrawerToggle(Activity mActivity, DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout)
    {
        super(mActivity, mDrawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.ns_menu_open, R.string.ns_menu_close);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerClosed(View view)
    {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.ns_menu_close));
        supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                                        // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView)
    {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.ns_menu_open));
        supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                                        // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
    }
}

private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener
{

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Tutorial.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

}

 }
```

**SecondActivity**

```
 public class Tutorial extends MainActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.help);
    }

}
```

Comment: I too tried it a week ago..without fragment will make the code very inefficient....so better use fragments.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

in `onCreate` of `TutorialActivity` don't call `setContentView` instead do this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.help, null, false);
    mDrawer.addView(contentView, 0); 
}
```

make `mDrawer` in `MainActivity` protected. and in  `R.layout.activity_main_drawer` just keep drawer tag and the element with gravity left(or right).

Comment: This is really helpfull, spent whole day. used this and got worked in seconds. Thankyou

Comment: please add R.layout.activity_main_drawer xml file to answer

Comment: What? Why don't use `<include>`?!

Comment: @СергейГрушин I think because DrawerLayout is supposed to be the top element. Anyway, I would suggest a better solution would be to use fragments now. If there is a way to user <include> do share how.

Comment: i remove setContentView() and write what u said ,but not working for me ... my baseActivity is open on SecondActivity .

Comment: How to use butterknife in this?

Answer (score 37):

Here is my implementation.. hope it help

**FIRST**, this [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18892294/2077479) is concept.

**SECOND**, this is also the [KEY](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21406760/2077479) one.

**FINALLY**, Here is combination of all answer in one place

---

**BASE ACTIVITY**

This is a base activity for all other activity

You can extends Activity or FragmentActivity or etc. base on your requirement.

`Navigation Drawer` setup here for one time.

```
public class BaseActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    protected DrawerLayout mDrawer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.base_layout);

        mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        //This is about creating custom listview for navigate drawer
        //Implementation for NavigateDrawer HERE !
        ArrayList<DrawerListItem> drawerListItems = new ArrayList<DrawerListItem>();
        drawerListItems.add(new DrawerListItem(0,"AIR° DEVICES"));
        drawerListItems.add(new DrawerListItem(1,"A/C Device [1]"));
        drawerListItems.add(new DrawerListItem(1,"A/C Device [2]"));
        drawerListItems.add(new DrawerListItem(1,"A/C Device [3]"));
        drawerListItems.add(new DrawerListItem(0,"AIR° FEATURES"));
        drawerListItems.add(new DrawerListItem(2,"SLEEP MODE"));
        drawerListItems.add(new DrawerListItem(2,"TRACKING MODE"));
        drawerListItems.add(new DrawerListItem(2,"SETTINGS"));
        DrawerAdapter mDrawerAdapter = new DrawerAdapter(this, R.layout.drawer_list_header, drawerListItems);
        ListView mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(mDrawerAdapter);
    }

}
```

**BASE ACTIVITY XML**

This xml layout is for `Navigation Drawer`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </FrameLayout>

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:scrollingCache="false"
            android:background="@drawable/drawer_bg"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**ALL OTHERS ACTIVITY**

Other `Activity` just extends `BaseActivity` and define code as below.

The `Navigation Drawer` will appear for particular activity.

`mDrawer` is form `BaseActivity`. it's a `protected` variable.

```
public class Screen1 extends BaseActivity

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        //inflate your activity layout here!
        View contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.screen1, null, false);
        mDrawer.addView(contentView, 0);

        //Do the rest as you want for each activity
    }
```

**SCREEN 1 XML SAMPLE**

Design as you wish it each activity. no more `Navigation Drawer` Layout !

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

</LinearLayout>
```

**NOTE**

In this implementation, The `Navigation Drawer` doesn't bind with Action Bar. If you wish to do that do it in `BaseActivity`.Also, This guide is not cover all requirement. It's just a sample.

Comment: mDrawer.addView(contentView, 0); giving error... 
What do I need to change to make it work ?

Comment: I followed these instructions, but my app crashes instantly when I press any of the drawer buttons.

Comment: Yes, it is not bound with ActionBar. And this is a real problem. I wasted many hours, but `onOptionsItemSelected` is not called, so, a back arrow doesn't work.

Comment: This really work. Now no more work with fragment in order to use navigation drawer.

Comment: Thanks, my friend

Answer (score 2):

I made a BaseActivity activity which extends SherlockActivity (or ActionBarActivity if is your case)

```
public class BaseActivity extends SherlockActivity
```

Then, make all your activities extends BaseActivity, like:

```
public class GlossaryActivity extends BaseActivity
```

Later, you must replace the activity layout with the one that correspond to your activity, I made a method in BaseActivity like that:

```
protected void replaceContentLayout(int sourceId, int destinationId) {
    View contentLayout = findViewById(destinationId);

    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) contentLayout.getParent();
    int index = parent.indexOfChild(contentLayout);

    parent.removeView(contentLayout);
    contentLayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(sourceId, parent, false);
    parent.addView(contentLayout, index);
}
```

I called this method on the onCreate method in each activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.replaceContentLayout(R.layout.activity_glossary, super.CONTENT_LAYOUT_ID);

}
```

`super.CONTENT_LAYOUT_ID` is the FrameLayout of the BaseActivity, and other param is the layout you want replace with

Answer (score 0):

You omitted the `@Override` from your derived class `onCreate`.

UPDATE: I'm not sure what the effects are of calling `setContentView` twice but that could be the problem. Separate out the code that sets up the drawer, and call that from both of the `onCreate` methods.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. This is my implementation:

**activity_main.xml** - the child at index 1 in the *CoordinatorLayout* is the **content_main.xml**, this I can change in code.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        **<include layout="@layout/content_main" />**

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I've created a class that uses inflates the others activities UI:

```
public class MyLayoutInflater {

    public void inflate(Activity activity, int LayoutResource, android.app.ActionBar getSupportActionBar, Intent getIntent){
        CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) activity.findViewById(R.id.coordinator);
        android.view.LayoutInflater inflater = (android.view.LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View contentView = inflater.inflate(LayoutResource, null, false);

        //change i so that it suits the child number in you coordinator layout
        int i = 1;
        coordinatorLayout.removeViewAt(i);
        coordinatorLayout.addView(contentView, i);
        getSupportActionBar.setTitle(actionBarTitle);
    }

    public void inflate(Activity activity, int LayoutResource, android.support.v7.app.ActionBar getActionBar, String actionBarTitle){
        CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) activity.findViewById(R.id.coordinator);
        android.view.LayoutInflater inflater = (android.view.LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View contentView = inflater.inflate(LayoutResource, null, false);

        //change i so that it suits the child number in you coordinator layout
        int i = 1;
        coordinatorLayout.removeViewAt(i);
        coordinatorLayout.addView(contentView, i);
        getActionBar.setTitle(actionBarTitle);
    }

}
```

Now on the other activities all you have to do is extend the MainActivity and call this method and give it the necessary parameters:

```
public class AnotherActivity extends MainActivity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        new MyLayoutInflater().inflate(this,R.layout.content_activity_another, getSupportActionBar(), getIntent());

    }
}
```

Comment: In your first `inflate` method you don't use `getIntent` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is hacky way to do this, I use it only for special kind of debug build to set properties of views in realtime (design tool).

It has advantage that **you can use your child activities as usual** without, special behavior that is required in different answers.

so in BaseActvity you can add:

```
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

// WARNING: Hacky, use carefully!!!
ViewGroup androidBaseView = (ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.content);
//this one in what child activity has just set in setContentView()
ViewGroup childContent = (ViewGroup) androidBaseView.getChildAt(0);

View drawerView = LayoutInflater.from(this)
    .inflate(R.layout.base_activity_drawer, androidBaseView, false);
FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) drawerView.findViewById(R.id.content);
androidBaseView.removeView(childContent);
frameLayout.addView(childContent);
androidBaseView.addView(drawerView);
}
```

and xml for drawer is just:

```
  <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/nav_drawer"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
  <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_for_components"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple and fast way to do it in android studio:

1. Create a new activity (Navigation drawer activity) from the gallery, and name it whatever you want, android studio will create everything for you (the class and the xml files that you can customize it later)
2. In other activities you should extend your Navigation drawer activity, and make sure these other activities has "no action bar" in the manifests file (android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar")
3. You should modify your other activities as follows:

   ```
   public class Mainactivity extends NavActivity
   {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      //inflate your activity layout here!
      View contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null, false);
      drawer.addView(contentView, 0);
   }
   ```

Note: the mainactivity will extend the action bar of the NavActivity, the NavActivity has a full functional action bar that will call the navigation drawer

I hope it will work with you

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays you should use **Single-Activity App Architecture** ([source](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/05/use-android-jetpack-to-accelerate-your.html)).

Then simple add Navigation Drawer to Main Activity

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use `<include/>`
By creating a nav drawer

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">
```

and then include the layout in it

```
    <include
        layout="@layout/activity_accounts"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

in your main activity make `setContentView(R.layout.your_drawer_activity)`

take note that if you use this method you have to create a nav drawer layout for every activity you have, unless you found a way to do includes programmatically.