# Map With Frgment and Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, dictionary, fragment

I have Two Problem in my Application

1. I have a Navigation drawer in my application where home is Fragment carrying  Google Map.
2. I want to show only 4 element in listmenu in navigation but I want to show navigation drawer icon and functionality in all the activities in the entire application.

Could any buddy please tell me answer of my two question.

In Map Section I am Using Following Code

**MainActivity.Java**

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.SearchManager;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

// nav drawer title
private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

// used to store app title
private CharSequence mTitle;

// slide menu items
private String[] navMenuTitles;
private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

    // load slide menu items
    navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

    // nav drawer icons from resources
    navMenuIcons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

    navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

    // adding nav drawer items to array
    // Home
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0],navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
    // User List
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
    // AR
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
    // TC
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));
    //BPI
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
    // BPP
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1)));
    //BPM
    /*navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem("", navMenuIcons.getResourceId(6, -1)));
    //BPT
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem("", navMenuIcons.getResourceId(7, -1)));
    //Logout
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem("", navMenuIcons.getResourceId(8, -1)));*/


    // Recycle the typed array
    navMenuIcons.recycle();

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

    // setting the nav drawer list adapter
    adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            navDrawerItems);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

    // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
            R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
            R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
            ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // on first time display view for first nav item
        displayView(0);
    }
}

/**
 * Slide menu item click listener
 * */
private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // display view for selected nav drawer item
        displayView(position);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    // Handle action bar actions click
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_settings:
        return true;
    case R.id.action_search:
        // search action
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

/* *
 * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
 */
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

/**
 * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
 * */
private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
    fragment = new MapViewFragment();
        //fragment = new UserListFragment();
        /*Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MapActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);*/

        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new UserListFragment();

        break;
    case 2:
        fragment = new ARFragment();
        break;
    case 3:
        fragment = new CommunityFragment();
        break;
    case 4:
        fragment = new PagesFragment();
        break;
    case 5:

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("Confirm Logout...");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure want to Logout ?");

    /*  // Setting Icon to Dialog
        alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.delete);*/

        // Setting Positive "Yes" Button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {

            // Write your code here to invoke YES event
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on YES", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
            }
        });

        // Setting Negative "NO" Button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO", new         DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // Write your code here to invoke NO event
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on NO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();

   //           finish();
  //            
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}

/**
 * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
 * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
 */

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);                   
}

}
```

**MapViewFragment.java**

```
 import android.app.Fragment;
 import android.app.FragmentManager;


 public class MapViewFragment extends Fragment {

 private SupportMapFragment fragment;
    private GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
        fragment = (SupportMapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        if (fragment == null) {
            fragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.map, fragment).commit();
        }


    /**
     * *at this time google play services are not initialize so get map and add 
     * what ever you want to it in onResume() or onStart() **/
    }

    @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            if (map == null) {
                map = fragment.getMap();
                map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)));
            }
        }
}
```

**mapfrgment.xml**

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

---

I am not able to understand Where I am doing wrong please help me.

Comment: Make a BaseActivity that implements Navigation Drawer, then all activities extends it

Comment: ok Dear Let me try this ..

Comment: Take look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25254794/4186942) to know how to Make a BaseActivity that implements Navigation Drawer, then all activities extends it.