# Android Navigation Draver

Tags: android, android-activity, navigation-drawer

Can some one please tell me how to create activities to this MainActivity that the Navigation Drawer will be seen in all of them? I need to use this specific MainActivity code. I don't need to use fragments, just 3 simple activities will be added to this drawer.

```
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
    import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
    import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
    import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_ingredients) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),IngredientsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_recepies) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_grocery_list) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

NavDrawer layout :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_ingredients" android:icon="@mipmap/ingredients"
            android:title="@string/ingredients" />
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_recepies"    android:title="@string/recipies"
            android:icon="@mipmap/recepies"
            />
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_grocery_list" android:icon="@mipmap/list"
            android:title="@string/grocery_list" />
    </group>

    <item android:title="Communicate">
        <menu>
            <item android:id="@+id/nav_share" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share"
                android:title="Share" />
            <item android:id="@+id/nav_send" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send"
                android:title="Send" />
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

Comment: If you want to share **the same** drawer you need to use fragments.

Comment: Do you know a working example? With easy set up?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare) is a complete example using the official `Android Design Library`

Also, here is some basic [training using fragments](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html) in case you are not familiar with them.

Answer (score 0):

One way to go would be to have your activities extend MainActivity.
In the other activities, you don't call `setContentView` instead, do this:

```
 View contentView;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

     contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_for_the_activity, null, false);
    mDrawer.addView(contentView, 0);
```

where `mDrawer` is defined in your MainActivity like this:

```
 protected DrawerLayout mDrawer;
 mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
```

This is explained in more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21405958/how-to-display-navigation-drawer-in-all-activities)