# How to merge two Activity in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio, android-tabs, navigation-drawer

I am having an two Activity in my project. In my DrawerActivity, I have added Navigation Drawer and in other activity i.e TabActivity I have list of fragments. I am trying to show content of TabActivity in DrawerActivity.
Is it possible to do so or I have follow another approach. I am newbie developer please help me out.

DrawerActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class Drawer extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawer);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.drawer, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

// And my second activity is TabActivity, here i want to show content of this   activity in DrawerActivity.

```
package com.umenit.naviagtiondrawer;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;

import com.umenit.naviagtiondrawer.fragment.EightFragment;
import com.umenit.naviagtiondrawer.fragment.FiveFragment;
import com.umenit.naviagtiondrawer.fragment.FourFragment;
import com.umenit.naviagtiondrawer.fragment.OneFragment;
import com.umenit.naviagtiondrawer.fragment.SevenFragment;
import com.umenit.naviagtiondrawer.fragment.SixFragment;
import com.umenit.naviagtiondrawer.fragment.ThreeFragment;
import com.umenit.naviagtiondrawer.fragment.TwoFragment;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TabActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), "ONE");
        adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(), "TWO");
        adapter.addFragment(new ThreeFragment(), "THREE");
        adapter.addFragment(new FourFragment(), "FOUR");
        adapter.addFragment(new FiveFragment(), "FIVE");
        adapter.addFragment(new SixFragment(), "six");
        adapter.addFragment(new SevenFragment(), "SEVEN");
        adapter.addFragment(new EightFragment(), "EIGHT");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so you want a DrawerActivity as a Fragment in your TabActivity?

Comment: what exactly do you want to show in drawer activity?

Comment: Actually i want TabActivity as fragment in DrawerActivity to show scrollable Tab+Swipe .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add navigation drawer to your other activities you can do that by extending DrawerActivity in your TabActivity.
For further reference check this link.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21406760/4646227

Comment: Well than it would be great if you can accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

in your drower layout you should add tab layout like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:layout_gravity="end"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout

    android:id="@+id/root_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                layout="@layout/tool_bar"
                />


            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/background_light"
                app:tabMode="fixed"
                />


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:textDirection="rtl"


    />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and in your code you should do this :

```
 public void setupToolbar(){
   // Initializing Toolbar and setting it as the actionbar
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ImageView drawer_icon= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.drawer_icon);
    drawer_icon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (!drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.END)) {
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
            }
        }
    });

}
public void setupTabs(){
     tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
     tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
}

public void setupDrawer(){
    //Initializing NavigationView
    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);

    // Initializing Drawer Layout and ActionBarToggle
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,toolbar
            ,R.string.drawer_opened, R.string.drawer_closed){

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            // Code here will be triggered once the drawer closes as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            // Code here will be triggered once the drawer open as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank

            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }
    };

    //Setting the actionbarToggle to drawer layout
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);


    //calling sync state is necessay or else your hamburger icon wont show up
    // actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();

}

public void tabListener(){
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            if(tab.getPosition()==0){
                NewsPage.newInstance(tab.getPosition());
            }
            else if(tab.getPosition()==1){
                MainPage.newInstance(tab.getPosition());
            }
            else{
                AnnouncementsPage.newInstance(tab.getPosition());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
}

public void drawerListener(){
    //Setting Navigation View Item Selected Listener to handle the item click of the navigation menu
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        // This method will trigger on item Click of navigation menu
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
            Intent intent;
            //Checking if the item is in checked state or not, if not make it in checked state
           // if (menuItem.isChecked()) menuItem.setChecked(false);
           // else menuItem.setChecked(true);

            //Closing drawer on item click
            drawerLayout.closeDrawers();

            //Check to see which item was being clicked and perform appropriate action
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {


                //Replacing the main content with ContentFragment Which is our Inbox View;
                case R.id.innovation_center:
                    MainActivity.position.setValue(MainActivity.CATEGORY,INNOVATION_CENTER_CATEGORY_NUMBER);
                    intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActionList.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    return true;

                // For rest of the options we just show a toast on click

                case R.id.about_university:
                    MainActivity.position.setValue(MainActivity.CATEGORY,ABOUT_UNIVERSITY_CATEGORY_NUMBER);
                    intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActionList.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    return true;

                case R.id.contact_us:
                    intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,ContactUs.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    return true;

                default:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Somethings Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;

            }
        }
    });

}
public void setupPager(){
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
}
```