# Which part of the code should I insert in every activity to show the navigation drawer in every activity

Tags: android-studio

I have an app that already show the navigation drawer in the activity_main.xml ... I do know about using fragments.What I want to do is to show the navigation drawer in every activity without using the fragments...Which part of the codes shoud I copy and paste in every layout to show navigation drawer in every page..Is there any code that I should add to the MainActivity.java or should I add codes to my drawer.xml?
Note: all fragments are put in one layout(drawer.xml)
Which part should I add or modify codes to show navigation drawer in every activity without using fragments?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add Navigation Drawer to all the activities in the application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18892074/how-to-add-navigation-drawer-to-all-the-activities-in-the-application)

Comment: check answer above... learn fragments, they're incredible useful ;-)