# Android: Navigation drawer on multiple activities

Tags: java, android, xml, navigation, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to implement a navigation drawer on multiple activities by creating a DrawerActivity that all my other Activities inherit from.

I have used the following 2 links to get me to where I am:

https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

[sliding drawer appear in all activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922641/sliding-drawer-appear-in-all-activities/4922740#4922740)

I can see the navigation drawer (grab handle), however I cannot open it from the clicking the title in the action bar nor can I see any items in the drawer. I can, however, open it from sliding across.

DrawerActivity.java

```
public class DrawerActivity extends Activity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private String[] navOptions = new String[] {"Collect Offers", 
        "Exclusive", "Glove Box", "Servicing", "Dealer", "Settings"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawer);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.nav_drawer);

        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this, R.layout.drawer_list_item, navOptions));

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,
                mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,
                R.string.drawer_open,
                R.string.drawer_close
        ) {

            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.app_name);
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.app_name);
            }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void setContentView(final int layoutResID) {
        DrawerLayout fullLayout = (DrawerLayout) getLayoutInflater()
            .inflate(R.layout.activity_drawer, null);
        LinearLayout actContent = (LinearLayout) fullLayout
            .findViewById(R.id.content);
        getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID, actContent, true);
        super.setContentView(fullLayout);
    }
}
```

activity_drawer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/infiniti_splash_2x">
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView android:id="@+id/nav_drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

HomeActivity.java

```
public class HomeActivity extends DrawerActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

activity_home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured out my issue. The problem was that by overriding setContentView it was called a second time (from HomeActivity OnCreate()) AFTER the ActionBarDrawerToggle had already been set. This means that I was basically overwriting all the work done in the DrawerActivity OnCreate().

Here is my modified code in the DrawerActivity

```
public class DrawerActivity extends Activity {

    protected ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private String[] navOptions = new String[] {"Collect Offers", "Exclusive", "Glove Box",
            "Servicing", "Dealer", "Settings"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawer); NO LONGER REQUIRED



    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void setContentView(final int layoutResID) {
        DrawerLayout fullLayout= (DrawerLayout) getLayoutInflater()
                .inflate(R.layout.activity_drawer, null);
        LinearLayout actContent= (LinearLayout) fullLayout.findViewById(R.id.content);

        DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) fullLayout.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ListView mDrawerList = (ListView) fullLayout.findViewById(R.id.nav_drawer);

        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.drawer_list_item, navOptions));

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,
                mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,
                R.string.drawer_open,
                R.string.drawer_close
        ) {

            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.app_name);
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.app_name);
            }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID, actContent, true);
        super.setContentView(fullLayout);
    }
}
```