# Sharing NavigationView with all the Activities?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, navigationview, android-support-design

How do we share `Drawer` with all the activities?

In the lister: `onNavigationItemSelected` of `setNavigationItemSelectedListener` we can get the `id` and navigate to it. What I am looking for is something like this:

```
private void initDrawerLayout() {
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        NavigationView navView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
        navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {


        Intent intent;
        int id = menuItem.getItemId();

        switch(id) {

            case R.id.home:
            case R.id.drawer_home:
            // call activity instead of adding/replacing fragment
            return true;

            case R.id.drawer_gallery:
            // call activity instead of adding/replacing fragment
            intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GalleryActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;

            case R.id.drawer_about:
            // call activity instead of adding/replacing fragment
            intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AboutActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        ...
        }
        ...
```

I know I can make all the `menuItems` add/replace `Fragment`, but then handling fragments and memory management is a big pain.

Instead I want each `menuItem` select/click to invoke `Activity`. i.e. each `MainMenuItem` to have `Activity` and those will hold fragments with complex layouts.

> All I want to do is have each main menu item be an `Activity` instead of a
> `Fragment`.
>
> And all these activities can share same `DrawerNavigation`.

Is this the recommended way? Or do we always add `Fragments` for `NavigationDrawer` item clicks??

Should I add `NavigationView` to `BaseActivity` and then extend all activities from there??

[Following this new guide about Support Design lib](http://antonioleiva.com/navigation-view)

Comment: yes, you should "add NavigationView to BaseActivity and then extend all activities from there"

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer using [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25865925/1336154)

**Extending is the right way. Just override setContentView in the right way...**

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit confused here as well.  After finding very little information on this I tried to extend my subclass

```
public class NewActivity extends MainActivity{
     ...
}
```

However, this alone didn't do anything.  the `MainActivity` has a fully functioning `NavigationView` that will navigate to each activity..Only thing that is left is sharing it with each activity.

Comment: I too added the Navigating code in BaseActivity, but then something feels wrong. As each activity that extends BaseActivity, will have redundant code and each Activity will be processing this information. I might be wrong on this but is this the only way out?

Comment: Parent activity should implement `NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` interface, so that child activities will be inheriting the menu navigation functionality of  `public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item)` method.